# For convex functions, how is domain defined?

Tags: optimization, reference-request, convex-analysis, definition, convex-optimization

[image]

Often times I see authors having a definition for convex function whereby they say that the domain of $f$ is a convex set.

However, how is the domain of this function defined?

I am asking because in convex optimization, there is also the effective domain, which has a solid definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_domain)

$${\displaystyle \operatorname {dom} f=\{x\in X~:~f(x)<+\infty \}}$$

So is their domain the same as the effective domain? If not, what's the difference.

Comment: You'd have to look in your book for the definition. It might very well be the same as effective domain, or the domain might be something specified for each function. But in that case it would be better to write $f:\text{dom} f \to \mathbb{R}$. For example, think about the function $f(x)=-\log(x)$, which is convex on its domain $x>0$.

Comment: The definition is sloppy. It should be something like $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to [-\infty, \infty]$ and then $\operatorname{dom} f$ is the set where $f(x) < +\infty$. This notation is ingrained in the convex world, and avoids writing out many special cases.

Comment: Following Rockafellar, I think that the definition of a convex function as one whose epigraph is convex is a better one. Some fussy notions such as properness need to be dealt with, but broadly the set based approach is convenient.

Comment: @jeff Hi, I am using another reference called "Convex Optimization" By Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vanderberge and they too do not define what the domain is. See Page 67: https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf

Comment: @ShamisenExpert See p.14 for a description of what they mean.

Comment: @copper.hat Hi Copper, it says, $dom(f)$ is all points for which $f$ is defined. So does this mean it excludes both $\pm \infty$ (hence is not the effective domain, because the effective domain only excludes $+\infty$)?

Comment: @ShamisenExpert In this case I believe yes, it is wherever $f$ is defined (that is, has values in $\mathbb{R}^q$). However, other authors allow both infinities, but $\operatorname{dom} f$ is used for $< \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

A convex set is a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all $x, y \in S$,

$$ tx + (1-t)y \in S \text{ for all } t \in [0,1]  $$

The domain needs to be convex because the LHS $f(\theta \mathbf{x} + (1- \theta) \mathbf{y} )$ should be well-defined.

The effective domain is a different concept from this, and is relevant when infinity is being dealt with. 
Here, $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$; and $\mathbb{R}$ does not contain infinity.

Comment: This does not answer the question.